# I keep getting the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'environ' in my settings.py file". I have installed the dependency in my python shell

Tags: python, django, environ

I keep getting an import error on environ in my settings.py file, I have it installed via poetry in my .venv file as well.  Could this be an error outside the settings file possibly?

```
`
import environ

env = environ.Env(
    DEBUG=(bool, False),
    ENVIORNMENT=(str, 'PRODUCTION'),
)

environ.Env.read_env()

ENVIRONMENT= env.str('ENVIRONMENT')


SECRET_KEY = env.str('SECRET_KEY')

DEBUG = env.bool('DEBUG')

ALLOWED_HOSTS = tuple(env.list('ALLOWED_HOSTS'))

`
```

Comment: if you have a virtual environment you're working with, make sure when you run your script it is run in that environment

Answer (score 16):

Make sure that you are using the desired python interpreter, that your [virtualenv is setup correctly](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html), and that the desired django-environ is installed within that virtualenv via

```
(inside venv) pip install django-environ
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem could occur due to the following reasons:

1. You are using. Virtual environment, but you installed module outside the virtual environment.
2. You haven't added 'environ', in your your settings.py file in INSTALLED_APPS.(based on its [reference](https://django-environ.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started.html#installation) exceptionally not required for this package!)

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  I installed everything inside of my virtual environment and am attempting to run $ python manage.py runserver with my virtual environment open and I'm getting "raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the SECRET_KEY environment variable"

Comment: Sorry for the late response. The issue seems like in your settings file, for secret_key value, you are getting value from environment variable. but environment variable is not set. 
SOLUTION :
1. either set up secret key variable value in environment variable on your computer.
2. set up variable value in setting.py file ...like secret_key = "any-random-text"

Comment: You don't have to add `django-environ` to `INSTALLED_APPS` for it to work:  https://django-environ.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started.html#installation

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have done the following three actions:

1. Install the package through this command:

   `(inside venv) pip install django-environ`
2. Select the right python interpreter(the environment in which you have installed the package)
3. Create an ".env" file in project root directory.
   And based on its reference doc [here](https://django-environ.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started.html#installation), it should be consisting of something like below:

```
DEBUG=on
SECRET_KEY=your-secret-key
DATABASE_URL=psql://user:un-githubbedpassword@127.0.0.1:8458/database
SQLITE_URL=sqlite:///my-local-sqlite.db
CACHE_URL=memcache://127.0.0.1:11211,127.0.0.1:11212,127.0.0.1:11213
REDIS_URL=rediscache://127.0.0.1:6379/1?client_class=django_redis.client.DefaultClient&password=ungithubbed-secret
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had one environ.py file that was clashing with the library import, changing the file name fixed the issue.

For Django there is another option that I use,

```
from os import getenv
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
```

create a `.env` file along with `settings.py` then you have to load those variables. For example :

```
CONFIGURATION = getenv("CONFIGURATION")
```

Install the module using

```
pip install python-dotenv
```